# Jobb crash FAT Full

Tags: android, crash

I tried to compile videos with jobb library the problem is jobb crash with videos larger in size than 500 MB, below is some information about this issue:

```
java.io.IOException: FAT Full (459872, 459873)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.Fat.allocNew(Fat.java:298)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.Fat.allocAppend(Fat.java:376)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.ClusterChain.setChainLength(ClusterChain.java:175)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.ClusterChain.setSize(ClusterChain.java:132)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.FatFile.setLength(FatFile.java:91)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.FatFile.write(FatFile.java:154)
    at com.android.jobb.Main$1.processFile(Main.java:495)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:604)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.main(Main.java:417)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting/writing file with name: videos.zip
    at com.android.jobb.Main$1.processFile(Main.java:501)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:604)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.main(Main.java:417)
```

Answer (score 1):

`file with name: videos.zip` - first, you don't have to use zip. You may use zip archive as expansion file itself, without packing it in .obb file. But using zip files may slow down your app.

Or you can just put your files in some directory (for example, "tmp"), and then call something like that: `jobb -d D:\tmp -o D:\main.com.example.1.obb -pn com.example -pv 1`. If each of your files is less than 500 MB, everything should be ok. But if not - I guess, you will have to think about another solution: maybe, compress big video files in order to make their size less than 500 MB.

P.S. For work with .obb files I created [this](https://github.com/uncleLem/AndroidUtils/blob/master/src/ua/a5/androidutils/utils/ObbExpansionsManager.java) helper you may find useful.

Comment: Just FYI, the naming convention for Android expansion files is (main/patch).(VERSION).(PACKAGE).(NAME).(HERE).obb. So if the package name was "com.example" (noting that most packages also have com.developer.product names) then the main OBB file would be "main.1.com.example.obb". ;)

Comment: @monkey_05_06 yep, seems like they changed naming rules. Thank you for information.

Answer (score 1):

As the OBB files are built on a FAT16 filesystem, the maximum total size is 2 GB. That could be consumed by a single file, or it could be made up of hundreds of files. Note that FAT16 only allows up to 512 files in the root directory, so if you have more files than that you'll need to have them in a separate folder inside the OBB file.

Uncle Lem is right that using a ZIP archive may in fact make your access to the files slower. Unless you absolutely need the compression (is ZIP compression very good anyway?), I'd recommend not putting the files into a ZIP archive. The jobb tool is designed to create a valid OBB file from the contents of a directory (including subdirectories, preserving directory structure).

The reason for your error is an issue in the jobb tool source and the FAT library it uses. I wrote in more detail about the specifics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18930268/1136311), but basically it's that the tool thinks FAT16 only allows up to 512 MB while in reality it allows up to 2 GB. Once the tool has been fixed you will be able to use it to create larger OBB files. In the meantime, it's possible to create a custom build that fixes it. I do later intend to publish my personal build of the tool.

[SuperFloppyFormatter returning FAT32 for anything over 512 MB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924872/superfloppyformatter-returning-fat32-for-anything-over-512-mb)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60294