# JWrapper Compilation error

Tags: java, jwrapper

The JWrapper team has graciously evaluate the software using their trial license. Unfortunately, while compiling my application using the latest version of JWrapper as of this time (version 00041299173), and with encryption/protection enabled, it spits out this error at the end

```
java.io.IOException: FAT Full (63898, 63899)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.Fat.allocNew(Fat.java:298)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.Fat.allocAppend(Fat.java:376)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.ClusterChain.setChainLength(ClusterChain.java:175)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.ClusterChain.setSize(ClusterChain.java:132)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.FatFile.setLength(FatFile.java:93)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.FatFile.write(FatFile.java:156)
    at utils.buildtools.osx.DmgInstallerBuilder.saveFileContentsTo(DmgInstallerBuilder.java:206)
    at utils.buildtools.osx.DmgInstallerBuilder.setupForApplicationInstall(DmgInstallerBuilder.java:274)
    at jwrapper.JWrapperCompiler.main(JWrapperCompiler.java:4156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at SecureRunner2.<init>(SecureRunner2.java:452)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at SecureRunner1.<init>(SecureRunner1.java:422)
    at SecureRunner1.<init>(SecureRunner1.java:227)
    at SecureRunner1.main(SecureRunner1.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at jwrapper.launch.JWCompiler.main(JWCompiler.java:112)
```

This doesn't happen using the unlicensed/free version, or when the "protected" argument wasn't used. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906055/what-causes-jobb-tool-to-throw-fat-full-ioexception - there seems to be some workarounds/fixes there that may be applicable

Comment: @Petesh Thanks. Yeah, I came across that before posting here. JWrapper's a proprietary application, so I can't do anything other than let the JWrapper team know about it and hope they address it soon.

Comment: You should be able to dissect the app's jar file(s) for the fat library and replace it with a functional one.